# how can i filter data from firebase firestore by multi field, flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore

*I Have a lot of fields,* **But I Can't Filter It**
I have collection has document's
[image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GQJwX.png)

I need to filter cars by for example **'manufacturing'** , **'price'** from and to

[image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HxULF.png)

Comment: welcome to Stack Exchange. Please see how questions should be asked (https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Further, please explain what you want to filter, provide some sample code of what you have done and where it isn't working.

Comment: "I Can't Filter It" Why not? What is keeping you from filtering it? Is there an error message?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. Also, if the links break, it would invalidate the question. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Please take a moment and review [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen  how many whereEqualTo methods can be used in a single query?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.